# Python struct pack mirroring

Tags: python, struct, pack, mirroring

Below is example of my code:

```
import struct

data = []
for i in range(5):
    firmware_addr = 128*i
    p = struct.pack('>I', firmware_addr)
    print("Addr: {0}, pack: {1}".format(firmware_addr, p))
```

Output:

```
Addr: 0, pack: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Addr: 128, pack: b'\x00\x00\x00\x80'
Addr: 256, pack: b'\x00\x00\x01\x00'
Addr: 384, pack: b'\x00\x00\x01\x80'
Addr: 512, pack: b'\x00\x00\x02\x00'
```

It is working fine. But I need to have output like this:

```
Addr: 0, pack: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Addr: 128, pack: b'\x80\x00\x00\x00'
Addr: 256, pack: b'\x00\x01\x00\x00'
Addr: 384, pack: b'\x80\x01\x00\x00'
Addr: 512, pack: b'\x00\x02\x00\x00'
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was easier than i thought.
Solution:
p[::-1]